# how to read image files and store it in memory(std::string) in c++?

Tags: c++, string, image, file, binary

i've researched online for most of today but could not find the answer so i'm turning to stackoverflow for some suggestion.

basically, i have a c++ library that uses curl to perform PUT method to upload an image file. now this library takes a std::string for data. i have image files (like jpg, gif, png) on my local disk.

i don't care about contents of the file (as in, i don't do anything with it besides passing it to this library for PUT method). how can i read image files and store it in std::string? what if the file content contains NULL terminator?

i tried to add some of codes i've tried, but i'm new here and i'm not sure how to paste my code here in the right format. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: To paste your code here, just indent everything by 4 spaces.  Or, paste your code, select it, then push the button that looks like this: `{}`.  You can also place code inline with your text by surrounding it with little thingies. I think they're called back-ticks.  On every keyboard I've ever used, it's the key in the top-left corner, left of the 1 key.

Comment: @Benjamin: On the German keyboard layout, it's in the top-right corner, left of the backspace key. :) You also need to press ctrl+alt to get it... In any case, `\`` is meant.

Comment: Do the library you use really want binary data in a string? You sure it's not the filename it wants? While the `char` type is a byte on almost all platforms, using `std::string` to store binary data seems wrong to me.

Answer (score 5):

Easiest method I can think of.  Open the file in binary mode, then read the whole thing into a `stringstream`.

```
std::ifstream fin("foo.png", std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
std::ostringstream oss;
oss << fin.rdbuf();
std::string data(oss.str());
```

Comment: this is what i did exactly. but did not work as it seemed to have uploaded just a portion of binary data.

Answer (score 3):

```
std::ifstream fin("foo.png", std::ios::binary);
std::string data;
data.reserve(1000000);
std::copy(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(fin),
          std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(),
          std::back_inserter(data));
```

You can read image files to `std::string` with code like this. Adjust parameter for `reserve` method to be larger than 99% of your file sizes. Zero bytes (which you call NULL terminators) are treated correctly with both `ifstream` and `string`.

---

I've found a good [article](http://insanecoding.blogspot.com/2011/11/how-to-read-in-file-in-c.html), where several methods of binary file loading are compared. Here is the fastest method from that article:

```
std::ifstream fin("foo.png", std::ios::binary);
fin.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
std::string data;
data.resize(fin.tellg());
fin.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
fin.read(&data[0], data.size());
```

And here is the shortest one:

```
std::ifstream fin("foo.png", std::ios::binary);
std::string data((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(fin)),
                 std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
```

---

**Update**

Something like this may be used to feed the callback function (I didn't test it):

```
std::ifstream fin("foo.png", std::ios::binary);
fin.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
...
curl_easy_setopt(m_ctx, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE,    fin.tellg());
curl_easy_setopt(m_ctx, CURLOPT_READDATA,      (void *)&fin);
fin.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
...
static size_t put_callback(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *data){
  std::ifstream* in = static_cast<std::ifstream*>(data);
  if(in->eof()) return 0;
  in->read((char *)ptr, size*nmemb);
  return in->gcount();
}
```

Comment: i have tried the shorted version on my code yesterday but this also didn't work. i'll try to get my code here today so i can get more help on this.

Answer (score 2):

this is how the library makes PUT calls where 'data' is string passed in as file content

```
stringstream data_stream.str(data.c_str());
curl_easy_setopt(m_ctx, CURLOPT_UPLOAD,        1L);
curl_easy_setopt(m_ctx, CURLOPT_PUT,           1L);
curl_easy_setopt(m_ctx, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE,    data.length());
curl_easy_setopt(m_ctx, CURLOPT_READFUNCTION,  put_callback);
curl_easy_setopt(m_ctx, CURLOPT_READDATA,      (void *)&data_stream);
curl_easy_setopt(m_ctx, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, get_callback);
curl_easy_setopt(m_ctx, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA,     (void *)&m_request_response);
```

and here is the callback frunction for curlopt_readfunction

```
static size_t put_callback(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *data){

  stringstream *output_stream;
  int          retval;

  output_stream = (stringstream *) data;

  if(output_stream->eof()) return 0;

  retval = min(size*nmemb,output_stream->str().size());
  output_stream->read((char *)ptr, retval);

  //return the number of bytes processed 
  return retval;
}
```

Comment: at least according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9612121/how-to-read-image-files-and-store-it-in-memorystdstring-in-c/9623954#9623954, string should be able to store zero bytes. hm.

Comment: Yes, string can store zero bytes. The bug is in the first line of your code: `data.c_str()`. Here zero-terminated string is passed as a char pointer. And so the string is trimmed by the first zero byte. Either remove unneeded `c_str()`, or use `stringstream` from Benjamin's method in the callback, or you can just open `ifstream` and use it in the callback (this approach gives better performance).

Comment: you're right. i guess i need to rewrite the callback function

Comment: I updated my post to give you some help in this. (But I didn't test it myself because don't have curl installed).

Comment: evgeny, thanks for the update. however i cannot open the file inside of the curl library. i have to pass in std::string for now. i've tested passing stringstream, and it worked for me. now i'm going back to using std::string to see if i can make that work.

Comment: I didn't suggest you to open file inside curl. You can pass there pointer to already opened stream. This does not differ much from passing pointer to stringstream or to string.

Comment: i found the easier solution which is to do data_stream(data) instead of data_strain(data.c_str()). this seems to work.