# Serialize PNG and Send to Rest Client

Tags: c++, rest, png

iam sending images in the png format to my rest clients.
But when i download the file on the client side and try to open it, i will get errors. 
I believe the Headers of the file are missing, but how can i add them to the serverresponse?

[On the details of my picture i can see, that the size and so on is missing.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZMBDg.jpg)

```
ifstream Stream;

Stream.open(FullFileName,std::ios::binary);
string Content, Line;

if (Stream)
{
    while (getline(Stream,Line)){
        Content += Line;
    }
}

Stream.close();
Request::request->set_body(Content);
```

Comment: Does getline make any sense when reading binary?

Comment: What would you use?  If i dont open for binary reading my code reads only the first line of the image.

Comment: This was a question of your code as well as a question for my own learning. It my mind it doesn't make sense to use getLine with binary, because a "line" could include 1 byte, or the whole file, depending on its contents. I typically read binary in sizes specified by the header, or at least in regularly sized chunks. I am not an expert on C++ however, so you or anyone else has input on this I am curious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching around found a post [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9612121/how-to-read-image-files-and-store-it-in-memorystdstring-in-c) on this side.

And the Sequenze i create from that.

```
ifstream *Stream = new ifstream(FullFileName, std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);

    std::ostringstream *oss = new ostringstream();
    *oss << Stream->rdbuf();
    string *Content = new string(oss->str());

    Stream->close();
    Request::request->set_body(*Content);
```